# Show and remove div animation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, slidedown

I have something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".green").slideDown("slow", function(){ });
});
```

```css
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 20px;
    display: none;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
    height: 20px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

Now I would like to appear the blue div in the same way, but when it comes up at the same time the green div is slowly disappearing from the top to down.

Comment: Is `$(".green").slideDown( "slow", function(){$(".blue").slideDown("slow");});` enough ?

Comment: can you be more precise about your issue ?

Comment: @gogaz Thank you but not exacly, because the green div should disappear from top to bottom while the blue div appears. I would like to make such animations that the green div collapses downwards and disappears and at that time the next div appears from above.